# The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

These are my entities:

```
public class Currency : Exchange
{
     public List<CurrencyPrice> CurrencyPrice { get; set; }
}

public class CurrencyPrice : Price
{
    public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CurrencyId")]
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
}
```

The first time I insert a value into the DB everything is OK but if I change any value in the DB and try to insert or update the record I get this error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

This is my insert code:

```
var currency =
    UnitOfWork.Exchange.Get(x => x is Currency && x.ExchangeType.Id == exchangeTypeId) as Currency;
if (currency != null)
{
    CurrencyPrice lastPriceValue = UnitOfWork.CurrencyPrice.Last(x => x.CurrencyId == currency.Id);
    if (lastPriceValue == null || lastPriceValue.Value != price)
    {
        currency.CurrencyPrice = new List<CurrencyPrice>
            {
                new CurrencyPrice {Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), EntryDate = DateTime.Now, Value = price,CurrencyId = currency.Id,Currency = currency}
            };
    }
    else
    {
        lastPriceValue.EntryDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    UnitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

I searched StackOverflow and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538974/the-relationship-could-not-be-changed-because-one-or-more-of-the-foreign-key-pro). But I don't understand what I have to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the problem lies in this code block:

```
currency.CurrencyPrice = new List<CurrencyPrice>
{
    new CurrencyPrice {Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), EntryDate = DateTime.Now, Value = price,CurrencyId = currency.Id,Currency = currency}
};
```

Here you create a new `CurrencyPrice` and assign it to a `Currency`, thereby orphaning the `CurrencyPrice` object that was assigned to this `Currency` before. This object is now still in the database, but without a parent. Thus EntityFramework wants to set the parent's ID on this `CurrencyPrice` to `NULL` which the database prevents resulting in the error you quoted. I have posted a more detailed explanation of this problem in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554696/ef-4-removing-child-object-from-collection-does-not-delete-it-why/3710278#3710278).

To prevent this, remove the old `CurrencyPrice` from your database before adding the new one. Alternatively, since it seems that `CurrencyPrice` objects always depend on their `Currency` parent, you might consider making this an identifying relationship. I have explained how to create them with EntityFramework 4 Model First at [Implementing identifying relationships with EF4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710191/implementing-identifying-relationships-with-ef4). I have not worked with Code First yet, but the approach should be similar.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I had the same exact problem, but my solution ended up being to just change the values of the list instead creating a whole new one and replacing it. Wish the error would've been alittle more descriptive; kept me stumped for hours....

Answer (score 0):

Had same error when saving changes on the context, and didn't made any changes to entities or relationships.

Error was because **some entities had GetHashCode() method ovveridden**.