# Entity Framework Error - The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

- VS2013, EF6

Having read all the SO posts this one comes closest [The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358293/the-operation-failed-the-relationship-could-not-be-changed-because-one-or-more) but I am not doing an INSERT and I am not DELETING anything (deliberately that is, AutoMapper may be "causing that effect")

I am getting this error when I attempt to UPDATE a record as follows. The initial INSERT works just fine. The supporting classes:

```
 public class UpdateStructureInput : StructureTableModel, IInputDto
{
}

   [Table("Structures", Schema = "dbo")]
    public class StructureTableModel : EmEntityBase
    {
        #region Public Members

        [ForeignKey("ParentStructureId")]
        public virtual StructureTableModel ParentStructure { get; set; }

        public long? ParentStructureId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SiteId")]
        public virtual SiteTableModel Site { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
        public long SiteId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }


        #endregion
    }
```

and here is the code that generates the exception after I have updated the Name field and left everything else the same viz: SiteId = 1, ParentStructureId = null:

```
public void UpdateStructure(UpdateStructureInput aInput)
{
    StructureTableModel structure = _StructureRepository.Get(aInput.Id);
    Mapper.Map(aInput, structure);
    _StructureRepository.Update(structure);
}
```

The automapper is defined as:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UpdateStructureInput , StructureTableModel>();
```

**UPDATE**
Additional code as requested. The repository and entity classes are built on top of http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/ so I have not included that source here as it is available from NuGet.

```
 /// <summary>
    ///     Base class for all entities defined in the system. This allows for the following
    ///     COMMON features:
    ///     - Primary key "Id" of type long
    ///     - Auditing which adds Date & User information for creation and update
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class EmEntityCommon : AuditedEntity<long>
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Extends the common functionality by adding the ability to mark a record as deleted rather than
    ///     deleting it from the database. Unless there is a reason not to mark an entity as a soft delete
    ///     then all entities should descend from this class.
    /// </summary>
    public class EmEntityBase : EmEntityCommon, ISoftDelete
    {
        #region Implementation of ISoftDelete

        /// <summary>
        ///     Used to mark an Entity as 'Deleted'.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }

public interface IStructureRepository : IRepository<StructureTableModel, long>
    {
    }

public class StructureRepository : EmRepositoryBase<StructureTableModel>, IStructureRepository
    {
    }
```

**/UPDATE**

I am guessing that for some reason EF believes that I have somehow orphaned SiteId when I do the AutoMapper call to assign the same value of 1 back to it?

How do I get around this issue?

Comment: What does `UpdateStructureInput` look like, and how did you define the mapping?

Comment: @GertArnold UpdateStructureInput is declared above StructureTableModel in the code above. I have also now added the AutoMapper configuration.

Comment: Is your repository eager loading the `Site` property?

Comment: @Moho No there is no call to Include() in that method, so Site is null as it is never accessed when the method is called. Only the Structure.Name is changed, so still leaving SiteId unchanged (and naturally Site is still null)

Comment: I am only able to reproduce when the navigation property is loaded and set to `null`.  Can you post the relevant repository code and `EmEntityBase`?

Comment: @Moho Added the classes you asked for, however the heavy lifting is occurring in ASP Boilerplate