# Calling .Remove() is executing an UPDATE statement instead of a DELETE and results in error: "Cannot insert value NULL into column"

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Here is the snippet of code where I am deleting my object:

```
var foo = this.repository.GetFoo();

foreach (var item in foo.RelatedItems.ToList()) {
    if (x == y) {
        //Update happens here; this isn't executing however.
    } else {
        //This code block is executed; this is where I am telling the context to mark this object for deletion.
        foo.RelatedItems.Remove(item);
    }
}

this.repository.Save();
```

When the `.Save()` is called, I am getting an error:  "Cannot insert value NULL into column".  I used the profiler to see what SQL was actually getting executed and it was:

```
update dbo.RelatedItems
set foreignKey = null
where id = X
```

I would expect a delete statement to be executed here, but, for some reason it's trying to update the record by setting the foreign key to null.

**Edit**

I added the following code to my repository class to solve the issue:

```
public void DeleteItem(Item item) {
    context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
}
```

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554696/ef-4-removing-child-object-from-collection-does-not-delete-it-why

Comment: @akatakritos - Thanks, that was my problem.  I spent some time searching for my error before posting, but, to no avail.  I'm going to leave the post here in hopes that my wording + Google indexing helps someone else out.  :)  If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this related question: [EF 4: Removing child object from collection does not delete it - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554696/ef-4-removing-child-object-from-collection-does-not-delete-it-why)

Apparently there is a semantic difference between `Remove` and `Delete` where `Remove` will just orphan the row by removing the foreign key, and `Delete` will actually take the record out of the table.

User `vittore` on the other questions suggests

```
dbcontext.DeleteObject(item);
```

inside the loop.