# Deleting a child object of an aggregate root in Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

This might be asked before but I can't seem to find a solution on the site so here we go:

Here is an oversimplified version of my domain model. I have 2 classes representing 2 tables in the database:

```
public Class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public virtual List<Contact> Contacts { get; set;}

    public void AddContact(string value) 
    {
        //some validation code
        Contacts.Add(new Contact(value));
    }

    public void DeleteContact(Contact contact) 
    {
        //some validation code
        Contacts.Remove(contact);
    }
}

public Class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Value { get; set;}
    public virtual Person Person { get; set;}
    public int PersonId { get; set;}
}
```

Now Person is my aggregate root here. I am trying to follow the DDD principal by only making the repository for the aggregate root. Adding contact works fine.

The problem I have is when deleting the contact. It gives the error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Is there anyway past it. If the relation property is non-nullable shouldn't entity framework automatically delete the contact.

Now I know that deleting from the collection is not the same as deleting it from the context but I don't want to reference DbContext from my domain model.

I only have PersonRepository.

Kindly provide a solution or help me understand if I am getting any concept wrong.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use the same class for for domain model and EF model. The EF model should only provide a means for servicing the domain model.

Comment: @JotaBe How can we do this exactly?

Answer (score 2):

That's a common problem when doing DDD with EF. Two solutions worked well for me so far:

1. Return the removed instance from your `DeleteContact` method. The method is most probably called from an application service which holds a repository. You can then use it to remove the instance from DbContext.
2. If you use [domain events](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/) you can use one to notify others about contact removal. You could then place a handler for this event in the infrastructure layer which would remove the contact from DbContext.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're having the same problem as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554696/ef-4-removing-child-object-from-collection-does-not-delete-it-why). Basically, when you remove the contact from the collection, you are not actually deleting it; you are only orphaning it, and in the process, setting its PersonId to `null` (which is not possible for an `int`, of course).

One possible solution is to make PersonId nullable in the Contact class:

```
public int? PersonId { get; set; }
```

Then, in your DbContext, override `SaveChanges` to automatically delete the orphaned records:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (Contact contact in Contacts.Local.Where(c => c.PersonId == null))
    {
        Contacts.Remove(contact);
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested that code but hopefully it is a good starting point.

Comment: Didn't work. WillCascadeOnDelete() works when you are deleting the aggregate root but not in this case. I just want to delete a child object

Comment: Of course, silly me. I've updated my answer; hopefully this is a little more relevant.