# Entity Framework 6: one-to-many doesn't update foreign key when inserting and removing in the same operation

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-many, navigation-properties

I have these classes in my project (the names in the code are in Portuguese, if necessary I can translate) :

```
public class EntityWithGuid : IEntityWithId<string>
{
    protected EntityWithGuid()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").ToLower();
    }

    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Servico : EntityWithGuid
{
    public DateTime? Data { get; set; }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public string Cliente_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Cliente_Id")]
    public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ICollection<ServicoImagem> Imagens { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class ServicoImagem : EntityWithGuid
{
    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public string Servico_Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Servico Servico { get; set; }
}

public class Tag : EntityWithGuid
{
    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public string Fonetica { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Servico> Servicos { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the `Context` configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ServicoConfiguration());
}

internal class ServicoConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Servico>
{
    internal ServicoConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasMany(s => s.Tags)         
            .WithMany(t => t.Servicos)
            .Map(mf =>
            {
                mf.MapLeftKey("Servico_Id");
                mf.MapRightKey("Tag_Id");
                mf.ToTable("ServicoTag");
            });

        this.HasMany(s => s.Imagens)
            .WithRequired(i => i.Servico)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.Servico_Id);
    }
}
```

After load a `Servico` entity the update method can do any operation with the `Servico.Tags` property (add and remove items), mark as modified and finally call `Context.SaveChanges()`. Everything works perfectly.

```
var servico = Context.Set<Servico>()
    .Include(x => x.Cliente)
    .Include(x => x.Tags)
    .Include(x => x.Imagens)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
...

// Remove tags
servico.Tags = servico.Tags.Except(oldTags).ToList();

// Add new tags
servico.Tags = servico.Tags.Concat(newTags).ToList();
...

Context.Entry(servico).State = EntityState.Modified;
Context.SaveChanges();
```

If I do the same thing with the Images property is only possible to make one type of operation at a time, **add OR remove**. If added and removed at the same time, the added item does not receive the value of the foreign key and error occurs in `Context.SaveChanges()` but if I do only one type of operation, it works perfectly.

The only solution I found was to make a loop to mark the item as deleted.

```
// Mark image as deleted
foreach (var imagem in imagensParaDeletar)
{
    Context.Entry(imagem).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
}
```

I would like to understand why the problem **ONLY** occurs in this type of relationship and **ONLY** when I need to do both type of operation on the same property.

Comment: I think you ran into this old problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554696/ef-4-removing-child-object-from-collection-does-not-delete-it-why The solution is to create an identifying relationship between ServicoImagem and Servico.

Comment: Do you think instead of delete the child EF is trying to update the foreign key to null?

Comment: Yes, removing the ServicoImagem from the collection sets the FK to null, but does not trigger cascade delete on the DB.

Comment: Thanks for the link made clear enough.